# Passing params using form_for not passing parameters to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing, form-for

I'm using a hidden label in a form_for. It is not passing the value to the controller. I've updated the params.require to permit the field but for some reason it is not passing the value.

The message I get on my console: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)

posts_controller.rb

```
def confirm     
    @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @post.toggle!(:confirm)
    @post.update_attribute(props: params[:props])
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

feed.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @post, :html => {:class => "form-inline"}, url: confirm_post_path(feed), method: :patch, :remote=>true do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only"><%= f.label :props %></label>
    <%= f.select :props, ['one', 'two', 'three'], class: 'form-control', prompt: "Give Prop" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Confirm", class: "btn-primary btn-xs form-control" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What prints the console when you make the request?

Comment: ` hidden label ` ? label does not contribute to form submit values...

Comment: @SebastiánPalma I added the console request in my question. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Are you expecting values from the `label` or from your `select`?

Comment: Which one is the hidden label ?
You might want to look at this - https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag to know how hidden tags work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm expecting the value from f.select. Now that I think about it, I don't think this question is relevant to the hidden field, I'll update the title.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I get the error on this line: app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:15:in `confirm' I'm not sure what to make of it.

Answer (score 1):

I overlooked something simple. My strong params was named post_parms so I changed:

```
@post.update_attribute(props: params[:props])
```

to

```
@post.update_attribute(:props, post_params[:props])
```